# Delphi Pos always returning 0

Tags: string, web-services, delphi, indy

I really don't know why Pos keep returning 0 instead of the char ";" position in string
I have to get a response of a php page which outputs a Content-Type: text/plain
So one example output is
`2;fulano;fulano;0 
3;ciclano;ciclano;0 
4;beltrano;beltrano;0 
5;foo;foo;0 
8;jose;jose;0 
9;maria;maria;0`

and the code is

```
var
  linha,uid,login,senha,email,tipo : WideString;
  resposta : TStringList;
  I : Integer;
begin
  try
    resposta := TStringList.Create;
    resposta.Text := frmMain.IdHTTP1.Get(frmMain.cdsConfig.FieldByName('WebService').AsString+'listdest.php');
    for I := 0 to resposta.Count-1 do
    begin
      linha := resposta.Strings[i];
      if i = 0 then
        Delete(linha,1,1); // the first line have one wierd $FEFF
      if length(linha) > 5 then
        begin

          uid := Copy(linha,1,Pos(linha,';')-1);
          Delete(linha,1,Pos(linha,';'));
          login:=Copy(linha,1,Pos(linha,';')-1);
          Delete(linha,1,Pos(linha,';'));
          senha:=Copy(linha,1,Pos(linha,';')-1);
          Delete(linha,1,Pos(linha,';'));
          email:=Copy(linha,1,Pos(linha,';')-1);
          Delete(linha,1,Pos(linha,';'));
          tipo:=Copy(linha,1,Pos(linha,';')-1);
          Delete(linha,1,Pos(linha,';'));
        end;
    end;
    //dlgWait.Close;
  except on E :Exception do
    begin
      MessageBox(Self.Handle,PWideChar(E.Message),'Erro',MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR+MB_APPLMODAL);
      dlgWait.Close;
      FreeAndNil(resposta);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: In this case, I would use a `TStringList` to parse the lines, not use `Pos()` at all. Set `TStringList.Delimiter=';'` and `TStringList.StrictDelimiter=True`, then set `TStringList.DelimitedText=linha`.  Or, use Indy's `Fetch()` or `SplitDelimitedString()` functions (since the question is tagged with "Indy").  And FYI, "*the first line have one wierd $FEFF*" means the text has a UTF-16 BOM in front of it, which is a bit odd for a webserver to send, instead of relying on the HTTP `Content-Type` header to carry the charset information.

Comment: @Remy I guess it depends on how many items are expected to be parsed out. Here, it seems like there will always be 4 every time, so I'd consider it safe and faster in all senses to manually parse it like this. However, if  there are many (such as 20+), or a variable (unknown) amount, then yes, certainly a `TStringList` would work great. But for only 4 values, I would think `TStringList` would be a bit too heavy for the task.

Comment: @JerryDodge: all the more reason I would opt for using `Fetch()` before using `Pos()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call to `Pos` is backwards. The parameters are:

```
function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _ShortStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
```

But your code assumes they are:

```
function Pos(const Str, SubStr: _ShortStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
```

So actually what it's trying to do is look for the value of `linha` within `';'`, which of course unless `linha` = `';'`, it will return `0`.

Another way to put it, as Rudy said, instead of looking for a needle in a haystack, your code is looking for a haystack in a needle.

Swap around the first and second parameters to these calls.

---

On a side note, just a tip for performance. Rather than calling `Pos` twice for each, keep a cached copy of the value...

```
P := Pos(';', linha);
uid := Copy(linha,1,P-1);
Delete(linha,1,P);
```

Comment: I usually use `Pos(Needle, Haystack);`.

Comment: such a silly mistake, these are the hard to find. thank you all

Comment: Even better performance is to use the `Offset` parameter of `Pos()`, and don't delete left-side `linha` content.