# Parsing output of wmic in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have recently used Inno Setup for my Java software. I am writing a function to check whether a printer driver exists by calling `wmic printer get name /All` and reading it output. But the problem is when I am reading the text file and check if it contains a specific substring by `Pos()`, it always returning 0, but when I tried to test with a character it returned the true value. I'm currently using version 5.6.1 Unicode.

I have looked at [Delphi Pos always returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804442/delphi-pos-always-returning) but I think it's not my case:

Here is how I did it:

```pascal
function isContainedInFile(File, Substring: String): Boolean;
var 
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  i: Integer;
  line: String;
begin
  Substring := Uppercase(Substring);
  Result := False;
  if LoadStringsFromFile(File, Lines) then 
     begin
        for i:= 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
          begin
            line := Lines[i];
            if (Length(line) = 0) then
                continue;

            line := Uppercase(Trim(line));
            Log('Substring:' + Substring + ', Line:' + line + ', Pos:' + IntToStr(Pos(Substring, line)));
            if (Pos(Substring, line) <> 0) then
            begin
                Result:= True;
                break;
            end;
          end;
     end;
end;
```

This is how I called the `isContainedInFile()`:

```pascal
function IsBrotherDriverInstalled(): Boolean;
var
  path, brotherPath, ListPrinterPath, ListPrinter: String;
  check, index: Integer;
begin       
  ListPrinterPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\printerlist.tdm');
  { Save temporarily the list }
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/c wmic printer get name /All > "' + ListPrinterPath + '"', 
                      '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, check);
  { Check if the list has the printer }
  Result := isContainedInFile(ListPrinterPath, PrinterName);
  { Delete the file }
  DeleteFile(ListPrinterPath);
end;
```

---

Here is my output when the substring has length > 1:

[image: Pos returned 0]

---

And when the substring has length = 1:

[image: Pos returned true value]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic` uses UTF-16 encoding in its output. `LoadStringsFromFile` does not support UTF-16 encoding. See [Inno Setup Pascal Script - Reading UTF-16 file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39844156/850848#39845057).

So the file is read incorrectly.

You seem to be using Inno Script Studio IDE. Its *Messages* console does not print messages accurately, so it obfuscates the real problem. Had you used original Inno Setup Compiler IDE or checked a physical log file, you would see the problem straight away:

```
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:ÿþN A M E, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:S E N D   T O   O N E N O T E   2 0 1 6, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:S A M S U N G   S C X - 3 4 0 0   S E R I E S   ( U S B 0 0 1 ), Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:M S   P U B L I S H E R   C O L O R   P R I N T E R, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:M I C R O S O F T   X P S   D O C U M E N T   W R I T E R, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:M I C R O S O F T   P R I N T   T O   P D F, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:H P   E P R I N T   +   J E T A D V A N T A G E, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:F A X, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
2018-08-26 10:44:35.783   Substring:BROTHER, Line:, Pos:0
```

---

Solutions:

- Read UTF-16 file correctly. See [Inno Setup Pascal Script - Reading UTF-16 file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39844156/850848#39845057).
- Or make the file be in ASCII encoding. See [Combine Batch/WMIC + ANSI/UNICODE Output formatting](https://superuser.com/q/812438/213663).
- Though the best solution is to use WMI classes, instead of the command-line tool. See [Is there a way to read the system's information in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40762683/850848).

Comment: Awesome. You right, I am using Inno Script Studio I should have used the original compiler. Thank you!